# remove 1st comma if exist, between double quotes

Tags: php, regex, csv

I have a string something like

```
'"This is string, some other text",,and more, and more'
```

I just want to remove the comma exist between the double quotes, the reason is I'm creating csv file from this string & strip the quotes before exporting. but because of the comma in double quotes csv isn't generating correctly

**Edit :**

Proper solution would using `strpos` for double quotes & then remove the comma if exists on the left side of the quotes (In some cases there is only one double quote i.e for inches)

Comment: then you're not generating your csv properly. Are you using `fputcsv()`? You can specify quoting characters in there, which'd make PHP escape the "extra" commas...

Comment: Use a callback, preg_replace_callback, with `'~"[^"]+"~'`, then strip all comma's in the callback, return the string.

Comment: @MarcB yes Im using `fputcsv()` but Im get a csv from api which I have to parse first and make it proper, then I do create another csv using php functions. so there are some limitations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a [**`preg_replace_callback`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) PHP function to match double quoted substrings (**in case there are no escaped sequences in your input!**) and replace the commas inside the double quotes inside the anonymous function:

```
$s = '"This is string, some other text",,and more, and more';
echo preg_replace_callback('~"[^"]+"~', function ($m) {
    return str_replace(',', '', $m[0]);
}, $s);
```

See [this PHP demo](http://ideone.com/jyW5as).

If you have escape sequences in your input, you need a parser.